# Es posible instalar una versión antigua de un paquete de GitHub en ionic con npm?

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework

Necesito instalar este plugin en ionic https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation sin embargo dejo de estar disponible y migro a una nueva, y ahora preciso instalar el plugin de otra versión que está disponible aquí: https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/releases

Se puede de alguna forma en ionic instalar vía npm una versión especifica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si conoces la version especifica que quieres utilizar puedes instalarlo de la siguiente manera:

`npm install paquete@version`

**paquete**: el nombre del npm que quieres descargar

**version**: el numero de version que deseas (por ejemplo: 4.2.1)

Un ejemplo especifico seria:

`npm install lodash@4.17.4`

Lo cual instalaria lodash en su version 4.17.4

**Actualizacion**

Debes considerar los requerimientos del paquete, ya que algunos cuentan con ciertas dependencias de otros paquetes en versiones especificas.

Comment: deberias de agregar a tu respuesta  que en algunas ocasiones las versiones anteriores corren con una version en particular de node  y puedes tener problemas con eso